# with 3 Parameters Function in R

Tags: r, parameters

How can ı make this problem?

with 3 parameters function

what is the 1 between 1000,  can divide to 9 and cant divide to 4 max and min numbers?

May be this ask absurd but ı am in learning process. :)

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following function. Note that though I called it with no arguments, it is a 3 arguments function.

```
fun <- function(n = 1000, a = 9, b = 4){
  A <- which((1:n) %% a == 0)
  B <- which((1:n) %% b != 0)
  x <- base::intersect(A, B)
  c(Min = min(x), Max = max(x))
}

fun()
#Min Max 
#  9 999
```

The second call asks for the smallest and largest numbers between `1` and `2000` that are multiples of `11` but not of `5`.

```
fun(2000, 11, 5)
# Min  Max 
#  11 1991
```